How can we process SQS events and store it in DB (SQL Server)?
I am using the Go programming language for my services and leveraging the AWS SDK for Go and SQL Server.
In our architecture, we have two major services:

Service A (Consumer)
Service B (Producer - Many)

We can only process 10 messages at a time due to the limitations of the library.
I have attempted to run the polling and ingestion tasks concurrently, but it is taking a lot of time to poll and ingest to DB.
Currently, I fetch 10 messages at a time and make an ingest call to the database for each message.
In one day, it accumulates around 600,000 events in SQS.
Could someone suggest a better approach to poll and ingest into the database faster?
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/v1.50.24/service/sqs/api.go#L7357

Architecture:


What A is? A lambda function?

No, A and B are microservices written in GO

What prevents you from invoking more instances of whatever A is?

Can the message from B be "larger" than just a single queue "thing"?

You should scale your A service based on the number of visible messages in the queue. If the action of handling a message is fast, this should be able to be handled by 10ish workers easily. Each worker should be able to poll the queue for the max number of messages and once it picks up the set, a go routine should be started to handle each message in parallel.
The Go service should not be the bottleneck here, it should be the number of connections to the DB. To aid with this, once you can scale A appropriately, you should pool your DB connections so that they can be reused easily - something like PgBouncer.
